# Eclipse plugin: Properties information not shown correctly when treeview is part of a tabfolder/tabitem

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, treeview, swt

I am developing an eclipse plug in with a tree viewer. Initially I had a single treeview of which I have displayed information of some elements in the standard eclipse properties tab. That worked without problems.
I have followed an example where I implement the IPropertySource and IAdapterFactory. In the method createPartControl() of the view I call 
        `getSite().setSelectionProvider(searchViewer);` 
which registers the properties.

Now I have added an swt tabfolder item to the plug in. Now In every new tabitem a treeview is displayed. That works fine, but the information in the properties tab are not shown correctly anymore. There's a strange behaviour though. On the tree elements which are of interest I have also added a doubleclick listener to do other things. After I double click an entry and right after single click on another element, the properties are shown for the doubleclicked element?!

I guess the problem is with the SelectionProvider. But I was not able to figure out how to implement it correctly now

Answer (score 0):

The properties view always shows the properties for the object that the selection provider says is the current selection.

If you have multiple tree views on several tabs you will have to write a custom selection provider (`ISelectionProvider`) that knows which tree is currently active and provides the appropriate selection.

For example, the following is a selection provider used by the JDT code for some things which you could use as a base:

```
public class SimpleSelectionProvider implements ISelectionProvider {

    private final ListenerList<ISelectionChangedListener> fSelectionChangedListeners;
    private ISelection fSelection;

    public SimpleSelectionProvider() {
        fSelectionChangedListeners = new ListenerList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public ISelection getSelection() {
        return fSelection;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(ISelection selection) {
        fSelection= selection;

        for (ISelectionChangedListener listener : fSelectionChangedListeners) {
            listener.selectionChanged(new SelectionChangedEvent(this, selection));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeSelectionChangedListener(ISelectionChangedListener listener) {
        fSelectionChangedListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void addSelectionChangedListener(ISelectionChangedListener listener) {
        fSelectionChangedListeners.add(listener);
    }
}
```

(`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.SimpleSelectionProvider`)

You would have to make all your trees call the `setSelection` method when selections change.